# Run docker without "sudo" in Fedora 24

Tags: docker, root, fedora

Although this post is tempted to be closed for many I should ask what I am doing wrong since I am getting crazy and can't find a solution.

I have installed Docker in Fedora 24 and everything seems to be fine but I can't run docker command without `sudo` and that's annoying (at least for me).

I am logged as a normal user (non-root) and as soon as I run a command I can see this message:

```
$ docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

However if I run only `docker` I can see a list of possible commands :-\

I've followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-centos-7) and I read also a lot (here is a small list):

- http://bsaunder.github.io/2014/12/21/running-docker-without-sudo/
- [Running Docker as non-root user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35849533/running-docker-as-non-root-user)
- [How to run docker image as a non-root user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891010/how-to-run-docker-image-as-a-non-root-user)

But certainly I am missing something, can any illuminate me? What I am missing here? I know the problem become user has not permissions to `/var/run/docker.sock` but what's the fix?

Comment: Probably because this post has more reason to exist on http://serverfault.com/ ?

Comment: @Jens I am not sure about that, let's see if you're right and if so apologies

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running `docker` to get the list of commands doesn't use a connection to the daemon, which is why you can run it as non-root.

Have you added your user to the `docker` group?

```
sudo usermod -aG docker <my-user>
```

If you do that, next time you log in you should be able to use the `docker` CLI without `sudo`. But beware that the `docker` group has root privileges, so this is a convenience but not a security improvement.

Comment: Excellent, I'd to reboot because logoff/login wasn't working (which I did in first) but after that it work as should be.